# The purpose of Reorder Library and IP fragmentation in DPDK

Tags: dpdk

Hello Stackoverflow experts,

I am trying to send 4096 byte of message by splitting the message into 4 packets.

However, Simply sending the messages in bursts does not guarantee that the messages will be received in order.
So I am having trouble to find out which library (Reorder library or IP fragmentation) will help me to guarantee that the messages will be received in order.

https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/reorder_lib.html
https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/sample_app_ug/ip_frag.html

For example if I send 3 messages in 3 bursts 
I receive messages like this below

ex) send (3 burst)
[1111111] [22222] [33333]

ex) recv 
[33333] [22222] [1111111]

So In order to solve this issue, I was struggling with reorder library and ip fragmentation in l3fwd example. 
Which library do I have to use in order to achieve  the result like this below? (IP fragmentation or Reorder Library)

ex) send (3 burst)
[1111111] [22222] [33333]

ex) recv 
[1111111] [22222] [33333]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, to fragment packet we use `rte_ipv4_fragment_packet()`.

To reassemble fragmented packet we should create a table of fragments with `rte_ip_frag_table_create()` and then use `rte_ipv4_frag_reassemble_packet()` function.

Please have a look [at Programmer's Guide](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/ip_fragment_reassembly_lib.html#packet-reassembly) and here is [a reassembly sample application](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/sample_app_ug/ip_reassembly.html).

The reorder library you have mentioned is designed to reorder based on sequence numbers, not fragment offsets. In other words, the workflow is as follow:

1. We assign sequence numbers to the mbufs.
2. We process those mbufs on different threads, i.e. the order is mixed now.
3. We reorder those mbufs back using reorder library.

So it is similar, but it is not the same as ip packet reassembly.